# Change the text on the message which is displayed after the user registration

Tags: users

I am looking for a way to replace the text in this message which appears on the website after a new account if created.

> Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently
>   pending approval by the site administrator. In the meantime, a welcome
>   message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail
>   address.

Has anyone managed to change this successfully?

Thanks!
Anton.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Admin -> Configuration -> Account Setting -> Change the messages.

OR

You can implement through [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

> Send mail after creating new user a/c

Usage :

1. Goto Admin -> Configuration -> Rule
2. Click on 'Add new  rule'
3. Enter Name & Select **React on event** : After Saving a new user a/c & SAVE
4. Click on **Add Condition** & select **Send Mail**.
5. Click on **Data Selector button** & Enter **Data Selector** : `account:mail`
6. Enter Subject & Message & Save

Comment: Hi Samzha,

Thanks for the descriptive answer, but you seem to be talking about the email message configuration. I am interested in the configuration of the Alet/Notice which appears in on the website when it reloads after a new user is saved.

Comment: Your question clearly define that you want to send the mail after new user registration. And this will done through Rules module. But in above comments you want to send message like Alert/Notice. May you please clarify which type of Alert message you want to send & for what reason & event.

Answer (score 0):

I would add another way...

You could achieve this easily via  [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) Module

> It includes a UI for quickly adding string replacements for anything that is passed through the t() function, which includes the message that you're trying to replace.

Comment: HI Pravin, thanks for the reply. I have been trying the String Overrides via the module and even via the settings.php file, but I must be entering the wrong string. Is there any way to see "In code" or via the Theme Developer module what is the exact string that is being parsed to taget it? I have been entering the whole message `Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator. In the meantime, a welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address.` but it's not changing anything. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that for the string overrides module to work you need put the whole target whole message string into string overrides, not just a part of it. For example if the string you are trying to replace is over two lines you would need to include the <br /> tag. e.g. 'Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.<br />Once it has been approved, you will receive an e-mail containing further instructions. was replaced correctly